# How to show fallback UI when errors are occurred in react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-error-boundary

```
import {ErrorBoundary} from 'react-error-boundary';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary fallback={<div>Some error occurred</div>}>
      <SomeComponent/>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  )
}

function SomeComponent(): null {
  throw new Error('error occurred')
}
```

The above code is *not working*.
The error is not catched. (Fallback is not shown)

But this code below is working well.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import {ErrorBoundary} from 'react-error-boundary';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary fallback={<div>Some error occurred</div>}>
      <SomeComponent/>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  )
}

function SomeComponent(): null {
  useEffect(() => {
    throw new Error('error occurred')
  }, []);

  return null
}
```

I want to show fallback UI when a child component function throw an `error`.

I've searched for official [documentation](https://ko.legacy.reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)

Comment: Is your `SomeComponent` returning some valid thing (null or jsx) on your first example?

Comment: No. as a result, I wrote the example like that because I had to be able to catch an error when I throw it through the child functional component.